# Sum function in Report Builder 3.0

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I am creating a report that will sum up all subtotal per MaterialNo/Color/Quality/Size.

Here's my sample report:

[image]

Computation will be **GrandTotal = sum(Subtotal)**

I am using `=Sum(Fields!TOTAL_CTN.Value)` but the result is 12.

Is there a way to compute using like `=sum(subtotal_TextBoxName)`?

Comment: It's not clear how your totals are being calculated. For example if you're just using a straight `Sum` of `TOTAL_CTN` for your totals, I would expect a Grand Total of **12** based on the above data.

Based on how you describe your grouping, I would also expect a Sub Total for each of rows in your report, but for *CCC* there is only one Sub Total, despite four different sizes. Can you please clarify: 1. Where the Sub Total grouping is applied? 2. How this affects the Grand Total?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Ian, for material CCC, we will put all four sizes(S,M,L,XL) in one box so the subtotal will be 1

Comment: yes 12 not 13.. thank you ian for your correction

Comment: How is that Sub Total calculated, though? Is is the `Max` of the individual *TotalCarton* rows? The average? Or will each *MaterialNo* group have the same *TotalCarton* value for each row, i.e. there isn't actually any aggregation applied? For *CCC* you have four rows, each with *TotalCarton* = **1**, so I would expect this to `Sum` to **4**?

Comment: SubTotal are calculated per MaterialNo/ColorCode/Quality/Size. All AAA will be place to 3 cartons, lets say its qty is 300(100per carton), for CCC lets say qty of 25 per size and will be put in one box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not 100% sure of your underlying data and business logic, but here's one approach that might help.

I'm working off the following sample data:

[image]

Based on what your description above, it sounds like you have something similar to:

[image]

Which gives results:

[image]

It seems that you don't actually want to `Sum` `TOTAL_CTN`, rather this should be the same for every `MaterialNo` with the `Sum` only applied in the Grand Total.

As such you can change the Sub Total aggregation to `Max` and, since you're using Report Builder 3.0, you can then take the `Sum` of the group level aggregation values. The report will look like this:

[image]

Where the Grand Total expression is:

```
=Sum(Max(Fields!TOTAL_CTN.Value, "MaterialNoMax"))
```

In this expression `MaterialNoMax` refers to the name of the Row Group (based on `MaterialNo` in my example).

This gives your desired results:

[image]

The key here is thinking about what aggregation gets applied at each level and how these roll up to the end total.

Comment: Thank you very much Ian, this is very helpful. Didn't think of using max function.